# Can not connect mongoDB remotely on centos

Tags: centos, mongodb

Previously I've installed mongodb 2.6 on Debian.

After installation I could connect to MongoDB remotely but when I've tried that on Centos, I just able to connect mongodb locally using this commend: `mongo 127.0.0.1:27017`.

Now I want to connect remotely and I see the port 27017 is closed. What should I do to enable mongo db remote access?

Comment: Open the port in the firewall?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is a non routable address. This won't work unless it listens to a routable address or `0.0.0.0:27017`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try opening firewall port on centos:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 27017 --syn -j ACCEPT
sudo service iptables save
```

This should really help. If you already opened iptables, you maybe trying to access it from other subnet or something similar. There is no other ways. If it still does't work, try temporary stopping iptables:

```
service iptables stop
```